# unknown option: --watch when trying to use jsx --watch

Tags: reactjs

I am following the react docs, getting started. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html. And according to it I installed react-tools via npm. And tried to do this `jsx --watch src/build/` I had helloworld.js(which contains jsx) in src, and I expected to generated the helloworld.js(plain js) in the build/helloworld.js. But I am getting unknown option: watch error. Where as jsx is getting recognized. So where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: there should be a space between `src/` and `build/`  
`jsx --watch src/ build/`

Comment: Tried that too .. same error.